# Designing Animation using jQuery - Need Samples

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I need to design small (and simple-looking) animations which would suit a board game.

For example, I need to coins which appear when points are won. The coins glide in a certain way towards the score-board.

Are there sample implementations for simple animations or some useful links that I could refer to for this purpose? (I have a feeling I am not too good with design.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**docs about the available animation effects**

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/

http://blarnee.com/wp/jquery-ui-animation-effects/

**tuitorials on how they are implemented.**

http://webdesignledger.com/tutorials/13-excellent-jquery-animation-techniques

http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/web-development/jquery-animation-tutorials/

http://sixrevisions.com/javascript/10-awesome-techniques-and-examples-of-animation-with-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

Try out the jQuery docs at http://jquery.com . Here is a link to the animate function of jQuery http://api.jquery.com/animate/ . With this function you can preform animations.